# RC4 decrypting a file using Java

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, hash

I have telephone exchange server which records calls and stores them encrypted. I need now to decrypt and convert all calls to .wav file.

I can see they are encrypted using RC4 algorithm, but I can't figure out how to get a key for a decryption.

Here's "`serverController.class`" from "`AgentServer.jar`:

> http://pastebin.com/3wVhhuqh

All records are sorted in two MySQl tables. Here's one record from both tables and it's corresponding encrypted file:

table "records":

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRwBN.png

table "recordsdetails":

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tEir.png

record file:

> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19586312/00000000000000000000

Can anyone help me please? If I could decrypt that one file, then I would know what to do with others and try to automate it.

Thanks!

---

```
private byte[] getRC4Key(BigInteger paramBigInteger)
   {
    try
{
  MessageDigest localMessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  localMessageDigest.reset();
  localMessageDigest.update(ServerModel.getInstance().getConnection().getPassword().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
  byte[] arrayOfByte = localMessageDigest.digest();
  localMessageDigest.reset();
  localMessageDigest.update(arrayOfByte);
  localMessageDigest.update(ByteArraysUtils.BigInteger2ByteArray(paramBigInteger));
  return localMessageDigest.digest();
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException)
{
  LOGGER.severe(localNoSuchAlgorithmException.getMessage());
}
catch (PbxOperationException localPbxOperationException)
{
  LOGGER.severe(localPbxOperationException.getMessage());
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException localUnsupportedEncodingException)
{
  LOGGER.severe(localUnsupportedEncodingException.getMessage());
}
return null;
}
```

I think that if I got a key I would be able to decrypt the file. Would anybody mind explaining me the way that key is generated?

Comment: So you link to a bunch of code that was clearly byte code decompiled, probably copyrighted by Platan in Poland, and then you ask us how to retrieve the key from a password and an unknown BigInteger. -1, would have been -10 if I could, but maybe others will help.

Comment: @owlstead that's true I don't own the software, but if a product owner doesn't want to help me, I need to solve the problem on my own because it's crucial case for me. Of course I have access to both password and BigInteger.

Comment: So what's so puzzling about `getRC4Key()`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hacking bytecode to retrieve non-public values, not programming.

Comment: @owlstead I spend few hours trying to figure it out without any success. I'm just an average PHP programmer and this is my first contact with Java. What's wrong with my question? Is that really prohibited to store files decrypted? Is that my fault that I bought a software that encrypts those files and allows (even administrator role user) to decrypt only one at once? With few thousand of records it's really tiresome to do it manually. That's why I'm trying to find a solution allowing me to automate that proccess. Don't blame me for this, please :-(

Comment: Do you think you've shown enough effort here? Just byte code decompilation in itself and then asking us to hack this thing for you is not how SO works. Ask specific questions about problems you encounter and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @owlstead I have updated the first post with a specified question..

Answer (score 2):

So it calculates `H(H(passwordEncoding) | paramBigIntegerEncoding)` where `H` is the MD5 hash algorithm and `|` means concatenation. You haven't shown us the code of the `BigInteger2ByteArray` in the question, so you may have to find how to encode the `BigInteger` yourself.

Comment: Thank you. That is quite similar to my thinking. While the password encoding is clear, this is how I tried to solve bigIntegerEncoding: http://pastebin.com/ikKdga9K It's a pain for me with all this static variables definitions in Java.. I would really appreciate your help.